# Error while installing MatlabR2011b

Tags: installation, java, matlab

Error while installing MatlabR2011b in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit OS

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_9756/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution provided by MathWorks

[Source](http://www.mathworks.in/support/solutions/en/data/1-DHWZAO/index.html?solution=1-DHWZAO)

> This error occurs when the installer file (for example,
>   matlab_R2010b_glnxa64_installer.zip or
>   matlab_R2010b_glnx86_installer.zip) is not extracted properly. This
>   commonly happens if the installer is downloaded on a Windows machine,
>   is extracted, and then copied to a Linux machine.
>
> To ensure that the installer runs properly, the installation archives
>   should be extracted on a Linux machine. To extract the installer, you
>   can use the command line tool "unzip" to extract the file. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> unzip matlab_R20*_glnxa64_installer.zip
> ```

The Other solution is to change the permission of the java executable located in **/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/** directory.

```
sudo chmod +x java
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used this path:

```
sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin
```

And I used the same command:

```
sudo chmod +x java
```